# PyQt6 program that lets you adjust the HSV values of an RGB color

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, pyqt

I don't know how to actually describe what this script does concisely.

I am writing GUI programs using PyQt6, and I want the most beautiful palette for my programs, so I browsed Wikipedia for a bunch of RGB values, and used them in my stylesheets.

The colors looked great, but there's one problem, my monitor has High Dynamic Range and I turned it on, the GUI only looks good when HDR is on, and when HDR is off, the colors look awful, they look greyer, washed out and less vibrant, I want my programs look good on any monitor and I must presume most users don't have HDR monitors.

So I wrote the program to adjust the colors to find the best palette.

The interface:

[image]

On the top row there are two boxes, one labeled "Original" and the other labeled "New".

In the middle of the first row you see two squares, the squares display the colors.

There are three rows in both boxes, corresponding to the RGB, HEX and HSV values of the color displayed in the respective box. Each row contains a non-editable QLineEdit that displays the respective value, and a label for that value.

Below the two boxes, there are three sliders, one for Hue, one for Saturation and one for Value.

Hue values have a range from 1 to 360, both Saturation and Value values can be 1 to 100.

For each slider there is a QLineEdit that displays the current value of the slider. If you drag the slider, the text in the respective QLineEdit will be updated. If you change the text inside the QLineEdit, the respective QSlider will be instantly updated, and you can't input invalid text.

Below the sliders, on the lower-left corner is a QLineEdit, it is used to accept the hexadecimal value of an RGB color (without hash sign), when you enter a value and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the program validates the input and will reject the input then revert to previous value if the input is invalid.

If the input is valid, both the original and new boxes will be updated and the sliders will be dragged accordingly.

When you drag the sliders everything is updated in real-time.

Finally when you press Random the program randomly selects a color from the full saturation spectrum (1530 colors total) and updates everything.

The code:

```py
import ctypes
import re
import random
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

DIRECTORY = str(Path(__file__).absolute().parent).replace('\\', '/')

ALIGNMENT = Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop
FLAG = Qt.ItemFlag

MAINSTYLE = """
    QHeaderView::section {
        background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #004060, stop: 1 #102372);
        color: #00ffff;
        border: 4px groove #102030;
        padding-left: 4px;
    }
    QScrollBar::vertical {
        border: 2px solid #204060;
        background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0, stop: 0 #004060, stop: 1 #00b2e4);
        position: absolute;
        width: 16px;
    }
    QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
        min-height: 32px;
        background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0, stop: 0 #00c0ff, stop: 1 #102372);
        margin: 18px;
    }
    QScrollBar::horizontal {
        border: 2px solid #204060;
        background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #004060, stop: 1 #00b2e4);
        position: absolute;
        height: 16px;
    }
    QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
        min-width: 32px;
        background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #00c0ff, stop: 1 #102372);
        margin: 18px;
    }
    QGroupBox {
        border: 3px groove #204080;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background: #002050;
        color: #b2ffff;
    }
    QLabel {
        color: #00aeef;
        font: 10pt 'Noto Serif';
    }
    QMainWindow {
        background: #001861;
    }
    QPushButton {
        border: 3px outset #4080c0;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 0.75, x3: 0, y3: 1, stop: 0 #4080c0, stop: 0.75 #00aae4, stop: 1 #4080c0);
        color: blue;
    }
    QPushButton:hover {
        background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 0.75, x3: 0, y3: 1, stop: 0 #4080c0, stop: 0.75 #b2ffff, stop: 1 #4080c0);
    }
    QPushButton:pressed {
        border: 3px inset #4080c0;
        background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 0.75, x3: 0, y3: 1, stop: 0 #4080c0, stop: 0.75 #005572, stop: 1 #4080c0);
        color: #00ffff;
    }
    QLineEdit {
        border: 2px solid #306090;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background: #202040;
        color: #b2ffff;
    }
"""

ALIGNMENT = Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop
FLAG = Qt.ItemFlag

def spectrum_position(n):
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        raise TypeError('`n` should be an integer')
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError('`n` must be non-negative')
    n %= 1530
    if 0 <= n < 255:
        return (f'ff{n:02x}00', f'255.{n:03d}.000')
    elif 255 <= n < 510:
        return (f'{510-n:02x}ff00', f'{510-n:03d}.255.000')
    elif 510 <= n < 765:
        return (f'00ff{n-510:02x}', f'000.255.{n-510:03d}')
    elif 765 <= n < 1020:
        return (f'00{1020-n:02x}ff', f'000.{1020-n:03d}.255')
    elif 1020 <= n < 1275:
        return (f'{n-1020:02x}00ff', f'{n-1020:03d}.000.255')
    elif 1275 <= n < 1530:
        return (f'ff00{1530-n:02x}', f'255.000.{1530-n:03d}')

def random_color():
    return spectrum_position(random.randrange(1530))

def rgb_to_hsv(rgb):
    r, g, b = [i / 255 for i in rgb]
    cmax = max(r, g, b)
    cmin = min(r, g, b)
    diff = cmax-cmin   
    if cmax == cmin:
        h = 0
    else:
        switch = {
            r: [(g - b), 360],
            g: [(b - r), 120],
            b: [(r - g), 240]
        }
        x, y = switch[cmax]
        h = (60 * (x / diff) + y) % 360
    s = (diff / cmax) * 100 if cmax else 0
    v = cmax * 100
    return tuple([round(i) for i in (h, s, v)])

def hsv_to_rgb(hsv):
    h, s, v = hsv
    if any(i > 1 for i in hsv):
        assert (
            h in range(1, 361)
            and not {s, v} - set(range(1, 101))
        )
        h /= 360
        s /= 100
        v /= 100
    
    if not s: return (v, v, v)
    i = int(h*6)
    f = (h*6)-i
    p, q, t = v*(1-s), v*(1-s*f), v*(1-s*(1-f))
    i%=6
    calc = [
        lambda: (v, t, p),
        lambda: (q, v, p),
        lambda: (p, v, t),
        lambda: (p, q, v),
        lambda: (t, p, v),
        lambda: (v, p, q)
    ]
    return tuple([round(255*j) for j in calc[i]()])

def hex_to_rgb(hex_):
    assert re.match(r'^[0-9a-f]{6}$', hex_)
    n = int(hex_, 16)
    rgb = []
    while n:
        n, v = divmod(n, 256)
        rgb.insert(0, v)
    if (l := len(rgb)) < 3:
        rgb = [0]*(3-l)+rgb
    return tuple(rgb)

def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    assert all(i in range(256) for i in rgb) and len(rgb) == 3
    r, g, b = rgb
    hex_ = (r<<16) + (g<<8) + b
    return f'{hex_:06x}'

class Button(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()
        font = Font(8)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setFixedSize(75, 20)
        self.setText(text)

class Font(QFont):
    def __init__(self, size):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFamily("Noto Serif")
        self.setStyleHint(QFont.StyleHint.Times)
        self.setStyleStrategy(QFont.StyleStrategy.PreferAntialias)
        self.setPointSize(size)
        self.setHintingPreference(QFont.HintingPreference.PreferFullHinting)

class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()
        font = Font(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.fontRuler = QFontMetrics(font)
        self.setText(text)
        self.autoResize()

    def autoResize(self):
        self.Height = self.fontRuler.size(0, self.text()).height()
        self.Width = self.fontRuler.size(0, self.text()).width()
        self.setFixedSize(self.Width, self.Height)

class Editor(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        font = Font(9)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setFixedHeight(20)
        self.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LayoutDirection.LeftToRight)

class Square(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(80, 80)
        self.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background: black;}')
    
    def setColor(self, color):
        self.setStyleSheet(f'QLabel {{background: {color}; border: 1px solid black;}}')
        self.repaint()

class Adjuster(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, maximum, value, label):
        super().__init__()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.setAlignment(ALIGNMENT)
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.vbox.addWidget(Label(label))
        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setFocusPolicy(Qt.FocusPolicy.StrongFocus)
        self.slider.setSingleStep(1)
        self.slider.setMinimum(1)
        self.slider.setMaximum(maximum)
        self.slider.setValue(value)
        self.inputbox = Editor()
        self.inputbox.setFixedSize(32, 20)
        self.inputbox.setReadOnly(False)
        self.inputbox.setText(str(value))
        self.currentvalue = value
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.slider)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.inputbox)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.setText)
        self.inputbox.textChanged.connect(self.validate_input)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox)
        self.setFixedHeight(51)
    
    def setText(self):
        value = self.slider.value()
        self.inputbox.setText(str(value))
    
    def validate_input(self):
        text = self.inputbox.text()
        if text.isdigit() and 0 < (num := int(text)) <= self.maximum:
            if num != self.currentvalue:
                self.currentvalue = num
                self.slider.setValue(num)
        else:
            self.inputbox.setText(str(self.currentvalue))

GEOMETRY = {
    'left': {
        'rgb_label': (0, 0, 1, 1),
        'hex_label': (1, 0, 1, 1),
        'hsv_label': (2, 0, 1, 1),
        'rgb': (0, 1, 1, 3),
        'hex': (1, 1, 1, 3),
        'hsv': (2, 1, 1, 3),
        'square': (0, 4, 3, 3)
    },
    'right': {
        'rgb_label': (0, 6, 1, 1),
        'hex_label': (1, 6, 1, 1),
        'hsv_label': (2, 6, 1, 1),
        'rgb': (0, 3, 1, 3),
        'hex': (1, 3, 1, 3),
        'hsv': (2, 3, 1, 3),
        'square': (0, 0, 3, 3)
    }
}

TITLE = {'left': 'Orginal', 'right': 'New'}

class Pane(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.setAlignment(ALIGNMENT)
        title = QHBoxLayout()
        if position == 'left':
            title.addWidget(Label(TITLE[position]))
            title.addStretch()
        else:
            title.addStretch()
            title.addWidget(Label(TITLE[position]))
        self.vbox.addLayout(title)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.rgb = Editor()
        self.hex = Editor()
        self.hsv = Editor()
        self.square = Square()
        widgets = [
            Label('RGB'), Label('HEX'), Label('HSV'),
            self.rgb, self.hex, self.hsv, self.square
        ]
        for widget, shape in zip(widgets, GEOMETRY[position].values()):
            grid.addWidget(widget, *shape)
        self.vbox.addLayout(grid)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        frame = self.frameGeometry()
        center = self.screen().availableGeometry().center()
        frame.moveCenter(center)
        self.move(frame.topLeft())
        font = Font(10)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        top = QHBoxLayout()
        self.leftpane = Pane('left')
        self.rightpane = Pane('right')
        top.addWidget(self.leftpane)
        top.addWidget(self.rightpane)
        self.vbox.addLayout(top)
        self.setStyleSheet(MAINSTYLE)
        self.setWindowTitle('Careyina')
        self.hue_slider = Adjuster(360, 0, 'Hue')
        self.saturation_slider = Adjuster(100, 0, 'Saturation')
        self.value_slider = Adjuster(100, 0, 'Value')
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.hue_slider)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.saturation_slider)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.value_slider)
        bottom = QHBoxLayout()
        bottom.setAlignment(ALIGNMENT)
        self.inputbox = QLineEdit()
        font = Font(9)
        self.inputbox.setFont(font)
        self.inputbox.setFixedSize(60, 20)
        self.inputbox.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LayoutDirection.LeftToRight)
        bottom.addWidget(self.inputbox)
        bottom.addStretch()
        rand = Button('Random')
        rand.clicked.connect(randomcolor)
        bottom.addWidget(rand)
        self.vbox.addLayout(bottom)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def randomcolor():
        color = random_color()[0]
        window.inputbox.setText(color)
        Stub.input_changed()
    
    def change_right():
        h = window.hue_slider.slider.value()
        s = window.saturation_slider.slider.value()
        v = window.value_slider.slider.value()
        hsv = (h, s, v)
        window.rightpane.hsv.setText(str(hsv))
        nrgb = hsv_to_rgb(hsv)
        nhex = rgb_to_hex(nrgb)
        window.rightpane.rgb.setText(str(nrgb))
        window.rightpane.hex.setText(nhex)
        window.rightpane.square.setColor('#'+nhex)
    
    class Stub:
        current_color = ''
        @staticmethod
        def input_changed():
            text = window.inputbox.text()
            if re.match(r'^[0-9a-f]{6}$', text):
                window.leftpane.hex.setText(text)
                rgb = hex_to_rgb(text)
                window.leftpane.rgb.setText(str(rgb))
                hsv = rgb_to_hsv(rgb)
                window.leftpane.hsv.setText(str(hsv))
                h, s, v = hsv
                window.leftpane.square.setColor('#'+text)
                window.hue_slider.slider.setValue(h)
                window.saturation_slider.slider.setValue(s)
                window.value_slider.slider.setValue(v)
                change_right()
                Stub.current_color = text
            else:
                window.inputbox.setText(Stub.current_color)
    
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    window = Window()
    ICON = QIcon(DIRECTORY + '/icons/icon.png')
    ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID("Careyina")
    window.setWindowIcon(ICON)
    
    window.hue_slider.slider.valueChanged.connect(change_right)
    window.saturation_slider.slider.valueChanged.connect(change_right)
    window.value_slider.slider.valueChanged.connect(change_right)
    window.inputbox.returnPressed.connect(Stub.input_changed)
    
    window.show()
    window.setFixedSize(window.size())
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

How can it be improved?

---

***Update***: I have redesigned the interface, refactored classes and restructured the code.

ICON:

[image]